# How can I use boost libraries in linux

Tags: c++, linux, vim, boost, libraries

I would like to use boost libraries however I have to download boost on Windows so I figured I would have to download that in a Linux environment if I want to use the vim editor.

Comment: Use your distro's package manager to install software.

Comment: This has nothing to with vim?

Answer (score 1):

on Ubuntu the easiest way is:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

on CentOs:

```
sudo yum install boost boost-devel
```